# Apache print syntax errors to console instead of logfile

Tags: apache-2.2, shell, httpd, syntax

Some of my apache configs are failing like this (because of a bug in control panel, but I need a workaround till this gonna be fixed):

```
/etc/init.d/httpd start
Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 30 of /home/apache/conf/domains/mydomain.conf:
RUidGid takes two arguments, Minimal uid or gid file/dir, else set[ug]id to default (User,Group)
                                                           [FAILED]
```

I would like to write a script that will automatically remove such configs, but when I type `/etc/init.d/httpd start >> error.log` nothing is written to file. The same happens when I try to grep a line from `/etc/init.d/httpd start | grep Syntax`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
/etc/init.d/httpd start 2>&1 >>error.log
```

It redirects also STDERR to STDOUT.

Comment: No, it still writes only [FAILED] to log file

Comment: Got it !

It should be: /etc/init.d/httpd start 2> error.log